# Nest Aggregation Search Request

Tags: java, c#, database, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch Aggregations via Nest. First, I am creating my requests in postman, testing them. When I see that they are working, I am trying to create via Nest.
But I wasn't able to create this request in nest:

```
{
"size":0,
"query":{
    "filtered":{
        "filter":{
            "term":{ "operationCode":"logincomplete"}
        }
    }
},
"aggregations" : {
    "operations": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "operationCode"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "login_count" : { "sum" : { "field" : "adet" } }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Current docs don't say much about aggregations in Nest. So I'm kinda stuck. So far I've tried:

```
var filterResults = client.Search<MCAOnlineExtRT>(s => s
            .Size(0)
            .Filter(q => q
            .Term(p => p.OperationCode, "logincomplete"))
            .Aggregations(a => a.Sum("login_count", t => t.Field(x => x.Adet)))
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
var results = client.Search<MCAOnlineExtRT>(s => s
  .Size(0)
  .Query(q => q
    .Filtered(f => f
      .Filter(ff => ff
        .Term(o => o.OperationCode, "logincomplete"))))
  .Aggregations(a => a
    .Terms("operations", t => t.Field(o => o.OperationCode)
      .Aggregations(aa => aa
        .Sum("login_count", ss => ss.Field(o => o.Adet))))));
```

Which will produce:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "operations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "operationCode"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "login_count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "adet"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "operationCode": "logincomplete"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how closely the fluent API maps to the json DSL, it's almost verbatim.  Also, `aggs` is shorthand form for`aggregations` in ES.